# How can I use Indexing api with App Script and in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, automation

I have a google developers account in google cloud console. I created a project, set up everything for it - key, credentials. I enabled the Indexing api. Now I need to connect it to App script and write the code there. However, all I can find is about doing with python.

I am not a programmer, please don't make fun of me. I'm just learning how to automate processes for SEO purposes.

I was sent a script that worked with google sheets and app script. I created a project in cloud console, set up the app script per instructions and now it's working. It extracts data in the sheet.

How do I set up the app script to work with the cloud console so I can start indexing urls?